# How to use new ASP.NET Identity 2.0 Roles and Authorize Attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am using the new ASP.NET Identity 2.0 system. I know I can check if a user is in a role like this:

```
bool isAdmin = UserManager.IsInRole(User.Identity.GetUserId(), 
   "Customer Account Admin");
```

I guess this code can be written to check before certain code is run but what about the [Authorize] attribute. I used to be able say:

```
[Authorize(Role="Customer Account Admin")]
```

This doesn't work anymore because I am not using the old membership or Role Management anymore. How can I put the two together? Or how do I guard against certain parts of the application not being available to members of the right role?

Edit1: I don't believe that it's working. I put the following Authorize attribute on an Admin page and I am able to execute the code as a "Customer Account User"

```
   [Authorize(Roles = "Customer Service Admin, Savitas Admin")]
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
```

Also, I would like to block that page from being seen by unauthorized users. We have code to block the menu but I can still type the URL to the Admin page and it can be seen by unauthorized users

```
 if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Customer Account Admin"))
                    //
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mi = radmenu1.Items.FindItemByText("Admin");
                        radmenu1.Items.Remove(mi);
                    }
```

EDIT2: We created the roles manually in the ASpNetRoles table and mapped users to roles in the ASPNetUsersToRoles table. There is a mapping from users to roles like "Customer Service Admin." We add users to roles with the following but I don't believe it works:

```
if (manager.AddToRole(manager.FindByName(UserName.Text).Id, "Customer Account Admin").Succeeded)
                                {
                                    c.logActivity("Register.aspx.cs", "REG_USER_ROLE", "Setting user to Admin role succeeded");
                                }
```

When a regular user logs in they don't get an Admin menu to the Admin page by typing into the address bar:

```
http://localhost:53620/Admin/default
```

How do I stop that?

Edit3: I tried to block all users to the Admin page per your example Eric but once again, I can log in as a Customer User and still type the above in the address bar and get to the page. What's wrong with this:

```
    <configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    ...
  </connectionStrings>
  <location path="~/Admin/default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Customer Service Admin" />
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
```

Edit4: Switching to path="Admin/default.aspx" gives the following config file error:

```
Configuration Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

 Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 



Line 66:         </controls>
Line 67:       </pages>
Line 68:       <membership>
Line 69:         <providers>
Line 70:           <!--        ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
```

Comment: Yikes, that's a hell of a reason not to upgrade.  I assume you could write a custom attribute if there's no longer a built-in way to do it.

Comment: You are making a wrong assumption.  The Authorize attribute works just fine with ASP.NET Identity.  The reason is that the Authorize attribute doesn't work with Membership or Identity, it works with IPrincipal and IIdentity, both of which are system agnostic.  Your problem is most likely because you have spaces in your name or have not enabled roles.

Comment: The error tells you the problem "This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS".  It sounds to me like you have a web.config in a virtual directory that is not configured as an application.

Comment: I had a web.config in the Account folder of my project but I deleted it. I can't get rid of the problem. I followed all the suggestions in a SO post here but to no avail. I am running locally in IIS Express.

Comment: I solved the problem. It was unlike the others on SO. I had two <system.web> areas in the config file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've performed several tests and I have not been able to recreate your problem.  I've used roles with and without spaces, and multiple roles.  And everything works as expected.

How are you adding the roles?  Here's how I'm doing it.

```
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>());
roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("This Is A Test"));
UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "This Is A Test");
```

UPDATE:

ASP.NET has three major components..  WebForms, MVC, and Web Pages.  You're using WebForms (not classic asp.net or any other term).

There are several ways to secure a page by role, but the easiest is to do it in the web.config using a location element.  Once again, this has *nothing* whatsoever to do with the fact of it being ASP.NET Identity or old style roles or whatever... it all works off the generic IPrincipal and IIdentity interfaces that are part of the base asp.net.  For instance the following allows all administrators to acess the site and denies all other users, but allows users in the MyUsers role to access CoolStuff.aspx:

```
<configuration>    
 <system.web>    
      <authorization>    
           <allow roles="Administrators" />    
           <deny users="*"/>    
      </authorization>    

 </system.web>

 <!-- Allow all "MyUsers" role users to access CoolStuff.aspx -->    
 <location path="CoolStuff.aspx">    
      <system.web>    
           <authorization>    
                <allow roles="MyUsers" />    
           </authorization>    
      </system.web>    
 </location>    
</configuration>
```

Please be aware however, if you're using routing, it's possible that that the same page can be routed to two different url's, which means that it could be accessible from one url, but not another if you are not careful with your permissions.

Comment: They were created manually by putting into the table ASpNetRoles. I believe that's where RoleManager puts them.

Comment: You need to do more than that.  You have to also map the AspNetUserRoles table

Comment: Oh, that table is mapped as well. It has an entry for a user and their role in it. We add to a role wit the following but it doesn't seem to work if (manager.AddToRole(manager.FindByName(UserName.Text).Id, "Customer Account Admin").Succeeded). I'll put this in Edit2.
                                {
                                    c.logActivity("Register.aspx.cs", "REG_USER_ROLE", "Setting user to Admin role succeeded");
                                }

Comment: @user2471435 - Oh, I see... Authorize attribute is part of MVC, it's not used by WebForms, which is what you're using.  You can specify roles in the web.config location element

Comment: Can you show a code example of this using the Identity 2 Roles? I knew it was stupid classic ASP.NET

Comment: Please see Edit3 above. I can still get to that page with the address bar.

Comment: Well, if that's your code, it's not well formed.. your missing the first `<`, you also have to make sure it's at the root level under configuration, not buried somewhere else.

Comment: Remove the ~/ from the start of path.  It should be just path = "Admin/Default.aspx"

Comment: Erik, are you sure it should be "Admin\Default.aspx"? Now I get a config file error on trying to go to the page, either as an Admin or not. I'll show this in Edit4.

Answer (score 2):

In Identity 3 you can use this:

```
[Authorize(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator")]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a roleManager enabled in a Web.config file like this:
`<roleManager enabled="true"/>`
you need to remove it.

Comment: Solved the issue for me! Thank you so much ( the only answer with 0 rating is the one who worked )

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem. I want to use AuthorizeAttribute to allow some web api calls to admin user.
[Authorize] works, but [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] doesn't. API calls with [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] execution are very long, and then I've got an SQL Exception (unable to connect).

I've added the role with the role manager. In my data tables, the Admin role is linked to my user.

There's something weird : the role is in claims.

If I do :

```
var claimIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
var roleClaims = claimIdentity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role);
```

I've got a claim with "Admin" value. I'm using it in an API call to return a different result to admin users, and it works fine.

The other weird thing is that I've tried to use instead User.IsInRole("Admin") and it doesn't work. So I guess AuthorizeAttribute uses IsInRole.

I'm going to write my own AuthorizeAttribute, using claim checking, but I'd prefer using the native solution.

Clément